# Does the Samsung NP700Z5A feature a Mini DisplayPort?

Tags: multiple-monitors, port, external-display

These are the specifications of [the Samsung NP700Z5A](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/office/mobile-computing/notebook/NP700Z5A-S04CA):

From these specs, here's a screenshot of one of the port sections:

[image]

Does the 'Display Port' in this screenshot correspond to a 'Mini Display Port' as described in [this Amazon item](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003OC6LWM)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update & Correction**:

- Which port that is depends on the size you get, 14"/15" = 15pin DSUB (pg 28/29); 17" = Mini Display Port (pg 27)
- Take a look through the [Manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201210/20121028102946143/Win8_Manual_eng.pdf) for specifics.
- This is apparently a "DSUB" interface, so you would probably need their cable.  I can't link you to which one confidently, since it varies (Start typing VGA in their search box, you will see what I mean)..  Maybe it's [this one](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs-accessories/AA-AV0N12B/US?)?

Bottom line, I would not buy a computer that is this opaque in what is on it.  I wouldn't want to dig through a manual to figure out what a part is, and that part not being an industry standard is unacceptable to me.  At least with Apple, you know that a "thunderbolt" port is a miniDP at heart and works with those.

Comment: what does 'DP' mean ? 'Direct Port' ?

Comment: can you add the link to the Samsung site, which states its "MicroHDMI" , I can't seem to find it ?

Comment: @user73076 - I was slightly off, updated to correct it and give you some documentation.  Note, I added a subjective "bottom line".