# Mystery port on my Samsung laptop (NP700Z5C)

Tags: port, external-display

What is the port in the picture of my Samsung Series 7 NP700Z5C?

[image]

It's called a "Display Port" [in this image](https://www.advance.no/pub/1205/5019029_NP700Z5C-S01CA-33-0.jpg) (not from Samsung, admittedly), but it's clearly not (the Samsung documentation even calls it "mini VGA" somewhere, which isn't a thing). It's the right general shape, but not even close to the right proportions, to be a mini-displayport, but it actually looks like micro USB. That left me thinking it's micro-HDMI or maybe , but that seems odd with a full-size HDMI port already just a few inches away.

[Samsung makes a specialty connector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007W1KES8) for like $40, but is it really proprietary? Is it just MHL or Slimport? Searching Amazon for "[Series 7 VGA Adapter](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=Series%207%20VGA%20Adaptor)" suggests it's micro HDMI, but I'm hoping for confirmation before I order something.

Hopefully somebody has this laptop and can clear up for me what this is - I just want to connect my laptop to VGA without paying through the nose.

EDIT:

I found [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/630637/does-the-samsung-np700z5a-feature-a-mini-displayport?rq=1) that makes me feel like I'm out of luck buying anything except the official adapter - it seems to suggest that what port it is depends on what size the laptop is and it's not consistent at all. That's unfortunate

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a Samsung VGA miniature connector.

It is Micro HDMI connector - [Samsung named it 12 PIN](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/office/mobile-computing/notebook-accessories/AA-AV2N12B/US-features)

But im not 100% if other brand connectors will work, if I recall correct we try vga connector from ASUS and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Image taken from the manual:

[image]

It's a D-Sub "analogue monitor port", aka mini VGA port.  Sadly there's no cable in the package to support it, you have to buy your own.  There are quite a few on ebay, luckily.

Comment: Yep, I searched on eBay for that model number in the URL, AA-AV2N12B, and a good number of them came up.